# Cannot delete \ in R

Tags: html, r, list, parsing, data-manipulation

Hello dear stackoverflowers,

I am using R but running into a problem:

How can I remove all the `\` characters from the following data? (I would like to get a list with these names without the \ but with the comma's and " ".  For example I want this:

```
\"TheKooks\", \"Anouk\", \"WithinTemptation\", \"dEUS\", \"Racoon\",
\"PeterPanSpeedrock\", \"Kensington\", \"LacunaCoil\", \"Di-rect\", 
\"SelahSue\", \"SickOfItAll\", \"TheBloodyBeetroots\", \"Therapy?\",
\"Typhoon\", \"JettRebel\", \"IamKloot\", \"Saxon\", \"JohnCoffey\",
\"HandsomePoets\", \"zZz\", \"KeesvanHondt\", \"TheDeaf\", 
\"MemphisManiacs\", \"Modeselektor\"
```

to become this:

```
"TheKooks", "Anouk", "WithinTemptation", "dEUS", "Racoon",
"PeterPanSpeedrock", "Kensington", "LacunaCoil", "Di-rect", 
"SelahSue", "SickOfItAll", "TheBloodyBeetroots", "Therapy?",
"Typhoon", "JettRebel", "IamKloot", "Saxon", "JohnCoffey",
"HandsomePoets", "zZz", "KeesvanHondt", "TheDeaf", 
"MemphisManiacs", "Modeselektor"
```

Comment: You can use `gsub`

Comment: Can you clarify what data you actually have loaded into R by showing us the code where you handle this content?  The issue is that you have escaped double quotes, which, when loaded into a vector, will be treated as unescaped double quotes.

Comment: In particular: `variableName <- gsub("\\", "", variableName)`. You need the first \ as an escape character for R.

Comment: Thanks lmo that was exactly my problem.